# Change " Tweaks " icon

Tags: 18.04, icon-themes

I use a custom fork of Papirus icon theme. When I modify `gnome-tweak-tool.svg` , nothing changes for the `Tweaks` icon. I want to use a custom icons for `Tweaks` at all sizes. Which file should I change ? Or which file name should I give to the `Tweaks` icon in the icon theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnome-tweaks is a application.
so look for this file in `/usr/share/applications/`
open it with text editor and look for the icon specified.

[image]

[image]

[image]

if you observe all these images are linked files to gnome-tweak-tool.svg in their respective size folders like 22, 48 etc

[image]

[image]

So, we have two options

1. either, directly deleting and pasting the required items in place of org.gnome.tweaks in respected folder with out linking.
2. or, again linking gnome-tweak.tool.svg files to org. gnome. tweaks.svg in respected folders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did add gnome-tweak-tool.svg in respective folders. It still shows the old age icon for `Tweaks`.

Comment: How do I link them ?

Comment: I use .icons folder.

Comment: Changing the name to org.gnome.tweaks.svg was the easiest and it worked for me. Thanks :)