# How to get a shortcut icon from a shortcut

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I'm trying to create a shortcut that opens the terminal by the following command

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

and would like to use the terminal icon for sake of clearance.

Where can I find it (the icon)?

Using ubuntu 18.04.

I do not want to create a shortcut (already did that), just need the icon.

Comment: It would be easier if you provided your release of Ubuntu.  Icons are usually found in /usr/share/icons/, but some I prefer can be found in /usr/share/pixmaps/ - it depends which you're exactly you're looking for.  Do you want the icon? or how to create a link (shortcut)?

Comment: I want the icon, already have the shortcut.

Comment: `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1114340/739431 may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal icon is a [standard application icon](https://developer.gnome.org/icon-naming-spec/#names) with the name `utilities-terminal`. You can use this name in your `.desktop` launcher (i.e. the shortcut you created) and then it would always assume the terminal icon provided by your icon theme.

Open the the `.desktop` shortcut you created using a text editor and look for the `Icon=` line. Change it to

```
Icon=utilities-terminal
```

Comment: I changed that, but the old placeholder icon that I had stayed, do i need to reboot or somthing?

Comment: Ok, none of that, i was just really dumb, this solution should have worked the first time, i just placed `utilities-terminal` in the wrong place. Thank you. How do I mark something as solved?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 the terminal.desktop is in the /usr/share/applications folder

If you open the .desktop file you can see the "Icon=utilities-terminal" entry which refers to the terminal icon. If you change your created .desktop file to "Icon=system-software-update" it will change to the updater icon for instance.

Comment: yes I see the terminal app there, but how can i "see" where the icon for the terminal app is?

Comment: If you open the .desktop file you can see the "Icon=utilities-terminal" entry which refers to the terminal icon. If you change your created .desktop file to "Icon=system-software-update" it will change to the updater icon for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what you want, nor your release of Ubuntu (which I'd use as a guide to work out exactly what you want), but most icons are stored in /usr/share/icons/

If you perform

```
cd /usr/share/icons
find -name gnome-term*
```

you'll be presented with a list of icons that start with "gnome-terminal" in all themes for your system (which vary on release of Ubuntu, if you've added any extra themes etc).  I'm hoping whatever you want is there.  (*my 19.04 system produced 91 results for this find, many of which are just different sized icons*)

eg.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/usr/share/icons$   find -name gnome-term*
./Humanity/apps/16/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/16/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/16/gnome-term.svg
./Humanity/apps/32/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/32/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/32/gnome-term.svg
./Humanity/apps/48/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/48/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/48/gnome-term.svg
./Humanity/apps/128/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/128/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/128/gnome-term.svg
./Humanity/apps/64/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/64/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/64/gnome-term.svg
./Humanity/apps/22/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/22/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/22/gnome-term.svg
./Humanity/apps/24/gnome-terminal.svg
./Humanity/apps/24/gnome-terminal.xpm
./Humanity/apps/24/gnome-term.svg
./Papirus/24x24/apps/gnome-terminal.svg
./Papirus/24x24/apps/gnome-term.svg
./Papirus/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.svg
./Papirus/48x48/apps/gnome-term.svg
./Papirus/32x32/apps/gnome-terminal.svg
./Papirus/32x32/apps/gnome-term.svg
./Papirus/16x16/apps/gnome-terminal.svg
./Papirus/16x16/apps/gnome-term.svg
./Papirus/64x64/apps/gnome-terminal.svg
./Papirus/64x64/apps/gnome-term.svg
./Papirus/22x22/apps/gnome-terminal.svg
./Papirus/22x22/apps/gnome-term.svg
./elementary-xfce/apps/16/gnome-terminal.png
./elementary-xfce/apps/16/gnome-term.png
./elementary-xfce/apps/32/gnome-terminal.png
./elementary-xfce/apps/32/gnome-term.png                                                                                                                      
./elementary-xfce/apps/48/gnome-terminal.png                                                                                                                  
./elementary-xfce/apps/48/gnome-term.png                                                                                                                      
./elementary-xfce/apps/128/gnome-terminal.png                                                                                                                 
./elementary-xfce/apps/128/gnome-term.png                                                                                                                     
./elementary-xfce/apps/64/gnome-terminal.png                                                                                                                  
./elementary-xfce/apps/64/gnome-term.png                                                                                                                      
./elementary-xfce/apps/22/gnome-terminal.png                                                                                                                  
./elementary-xfce/apps/22/gnome-term.png                                                                                                                      
./elementary-xfce/apps/24/gnome-terminal.png
./elementary-xfce/apps/24/gnome-term.png
./Yaru/24x24/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/32x32/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/32x32@2x/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/16x16/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/256x256@2x/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/24x24@2x/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/scalable/apps/gnome-terminal-symbolic.svg
./Yaru/16x16@2x/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/48x48@2x/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./Yaru/256x256/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./gnome/24x24/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./gnome/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./gnome/32x32/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./gnome/16x16/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./gnome/22x22/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./gnome/256x256/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./mate/24x24/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./mate/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./mate/32x32/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./mate/16x16/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./mate/22x22/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./mate/256x256/apps/gnome-terminal.png
./elementary/apps/16/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/16/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/16/gnome-term.svg
./elementary/apps/32/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/32/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/32/gnome-term.svg
./elementary/apps/48/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/48/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/48/gnome-term.svg
./elementary/apps/128/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/128/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/128/gnome-term.svg
./elementary/apps/64/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/64/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/64/gnome-term.svg
./elementary/apps/22/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/22/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/22/gnome-term.svg
./elementary/apps/24/gnome-terminal.svg
./elementary/apps/24/gnome-terminal.xpm
./elementary/apps/24/gnome-term.svg
```

Comment: Now see, that's the problem, I've been in that file but gnome-terminal icon are only in svg and xpm types, when i try to choose a new icon for my shortcut those don't appear. I assum it only takes pngs or smth like that.

Comment: I don't have all those png ones. It would be great if you could just drop that 48x48, thanks

Comment: drop?  sorry I don't know what you mean.  A quick scan of my files show some .png in package `elementary-xfce-icon-theme` & `elementary-icon-theme`  (I have XFCE desktop added to my system, along with LXQt).  The YARU theme I think was added in 18.10 and is in `yaru-theme-icon`.

Comment: upload, send me, i don't know if it can be done in this forums.

Comment: I wondered if that's what you meant - why I added the package names (so you can just grab them yourself).  A `dpkg -S /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.png` reveals 
*gnome-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.png*  (ie. I asked my system where that file comes from - package is `gnome-icon-theme` - just install that for that file (and whatever else comes in that package)

Comment: elementary-icon-theme dos have a terminal icon, its not the exact same but it is good enough.

Comment: I would assume it's in the `gnome-icon-theme` package in my last list, but again your question wasn't very specific (a picture would probably have been necessary)

Answer (score 0):

The command in 18.04 is

```
gnome-terminal
```

the icon appears automatically.

[image: Terminal]

[image: Icon]